# Max and Min continuous in general topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Futhermore $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions mapping to $\mathbb R$.

Is it true that $\text{min}(f,g): X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\min(a,b)=\dfrac{1}{2}(a+b-|a-b|)$

Edit: fixed formula for min

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Now I have a composition of continuous functions since the absolute value is continuous.

Comment: @Peter Correct. You need to know that the sum of continuous functions is continuous, which can be done without knowledge of the product topology.

Comment: It's true for ordered spaces generally, (see my answer), which I prefer to using the topological group (plus norm) structure.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It depends on the OP's background; in my opinion this was a very basic exercise, so dealing with ordered topological spaces could be much beyond what the OP has studied.

Comment: It's a missed opportunity IMHO: any course in general topology should give ordered spaces as one of the first examples (with the metric ones).. Too bad this isn't so common.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I may agree if the course is for students in mathematics. In many other situations, just metric spaces are dealt with, because greater generality is not needed and requires too much time for being developed.

Answer (score 2):

I think yes that is true. Take this function $h(x)= \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}-\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}$. So if f(x)>g(x), then h(x)=min(f(x),g(x))=g(x) and vice versa for g(x)>f(x). So h is continuous as sum of two continuous function and modulus of continuous function is continuous.

Comment: Not "by definition". There are hidden theorems here...

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the mapping $F \colon X \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x) = (f(x),g(x))$ and compose it with the mapping $\min \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined in the obvious way. Thus it is enough to prove that the function $\min$ is continuous.

Comment: This assumes you know about the product topology.

Answer (score 1):

This is true when $f$ and $g$ take values in any ordered topological space $(Y, <)$, in fact. Let $h(x) = \min(f(x), g(x))$. For all $y \in Y$:

$$x \in h^{-1}[(\leftarrow, y)] \leftrightarrow h(x) < y \leftrightarrow (f(x) < y \lor g(x) < y) \leftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}[(\leftarrow, y)] \cup g^{-1}[(\leftarrow, y)]\text{,}$$

and

$$x \in h^{-1}[(y, \rightarrow)] \leftrightarrow h(x) > y \leftrightarrow (f(x) > y \land g(x) > y) \leftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}[(y, \rightarrow)] \cap g^{-1}[(y, \rightarrow)]\text{.}$$

Which shows that the inverse images of $h$ of subbasic elements are open (when $f$ and $g$ are continuous), and so $h$ is continuous. It also quite easily shows the same for the $\max$ function (we only need to interchange the lines, sort of).